# Need to write subquery to calculate income for each month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My table is like

```
summa_som     date_operation
  -----     -------------- 
  100       11/03/2005
  500       13/07/2008
  900       12/11/2015
```

Expected result

I want to calculate income for each month there should 3 columns:
income, month and year:

```
Income      Month        Year   
------      --------     ----
10000       February     2015    
15000       December     2015
```

I have tried this but, I do not understand well how sub-queries work. This code should give an idea of what I want:

```
select max(summa_som * 0.01) income
from t_operation
where to_char(date_operation,'MM') = 11
and to_char(date_operation,'YYYY') = 2015
( select max(summa_som * 0.01) income_for_dec2015 from t_operation
where to_char(date_operation,'MM') = 12
and to_char(date_operation,'YYYY') = 2015 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter and aggregation to achieve this:

```
select to_char(date_operation, 'Month') as mn,
    to_char(date_operation, 'YYYY') as yr,
    max(summa_som) * 0.01 as income
from t_operation
where date_operation >= date '2015-11-01'
    and date_operation < date '2016-01-01'
group by to_char(date_operation, 'Month'),
    to_char(date_operation, 'YYYY')
```

If you want result of all the months and years for which the data is present, you can remove the filter condition.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have some specific formatting concerns with date and something going on with the income by multiplying it by 0.01.  When you have formatting concerns like this, I prefer to do the aggregation in an inner query based on the data types involved, keeping numbers as numbers and dates, even it modified for grouping as dates.  Then, wrap the statement with an outer query that handles type conversions or formatting.

```
select (income*0.01) as income_value, 
       to_char(income_mn,'Month') as income_month,
       to_char(income_mn,'YYYY') as income_year
from (
      select trunc(date_operation,'MON') as income_mn, 
             max(summa_som) as income
      from   t_operation
      where  date_operation between to_date('11/2015','MM/YYYY')
                                and to_date('01/2016','MM/YYYY') - numtodsinterval(1, 'SECOND')
      group by trunc(date_operation,'MON')
     );
```

note: using between makes the both the upper and lower bound values inclusive.  I've subtracted one second to the upper bound to only include the December values, but this is not really necessary unless you only want 2015 values.